# Draw Pixel Array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, grayscale

I have array of 1 & 0. 1 is for black and 0 is for white. I want the fastest method to draw/render, invert the pixel color, and resize the drawing in iOS. I have written this code but it seems slow:

```
for (int yCoordinate = 0; yCoordinate < height; yCoordinate++)
{
for (int xCoordinate = 0; xCoordinate < width; xCoordinate++)
{
int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yCoordinate) + xCoordinate * bytesPerPixel;
        int pixel = jbig2_image_get_pixel(imgData, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        float pixelRGB[]={0,0,0,0};

        if(pixel==0)
        {
            pixelRGB[0] = backRGB[0];  //255.f;
            pixelRGB[1] = backRGB[1];
            pixelRGB[2] = backRGB[2];
            pixelRGB[3] = backRGB[3];

        }

        else
        {
            pixelRGB[0] =  textRGB[0]; //0.f
            pixelRGB[1] =  textRGB[1];
            pixelRGB[2] =  textRGB[2];
            pixelRGB[3] =  textRGB[3];

        }


//Assigning new color components

rawData[byteIndex] = (unsigned char) pixelRGB[0];
rawData[byteIndex + 1] = (unsigned char) pixelRGB[1];
rawData[byteIndex + 2] = (unsigned char) pixelRGB[2];
        rawData[byteIndex + 3] = (unsigned char) pixelRGB[3];


}
}

CGColorSpaceRef  colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                      width,
                                      height,
                                      8,
                                      bytesPerRow,
                                      colorSpace,
                                      (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);


CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Is there any better method like CGLayer, UIKit, etc. I would really appreciate if someone provide me a sample code and the better & faster method

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CGBitmapCreate()` and create a 1-bit per pixel image. (Note that you'll have to convert your byte array into a bitmap where each byte in the byte array becomes a single bit in the bitmap.) You can then create the `UIImage` directly from the 1-bit per pixel `CGImage`. To invert it, you can draw using a different blend mode (maybe difference mode or possibly XOR?).